# Radio click event not working with checkboxes with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox like so with the class name `anotherCheese`, When someone clicks on that it will append to the steps-row-first class, what is being appended also has a radio button with the class name `anotherCheese`, but my click event does not get called on the new radio button with the class name `anotherCheese`, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="steps-row-first">
<div class="radio-wrapper">
              <div class="radio-group">
                <input type="radio" class="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="yes" />
                <label>Yes</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio-group">
                <input type="radio" name="anotherCheese" value="no" />
                <label>No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.anotherCheese').on("click", function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'yes')
    {
      $(".steps-row-first").append('<div class="radio-wrapper"> <div class="radio-group"> <input type="radio" class="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="yes"/> <label>Yes</label> </div><div class="radio-group"> <input type="radio" name="anotherCheese" value="no"/> <label>No</label> </div></div>');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the event to an ancestor element like `.step-row-first`. There's some changes to the example below, but in essence, by binding to an ancestor element, you can leverage event bubbling and control all behavior of children elements -- this is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

In the following example:

- `.step-row-first` is a `<form>`
- "click" event is now ["change" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).
- Note the second parameter is: `".anotherCheese"`, which designates it as `this`.
- `<div>` changed to `<fieldset>` for [semantics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics).

BTW, since you're not using any `#id`s (good choice), you could use [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) you just got to have the clone unchecked before appending it.

```js
$(".steps-row-first").on("change", ".anotherCheese", function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
    $(".steps-row-first").append(`
    <fieldset class="radio-wrapper">
      <fieldset class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" class="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="yes" />
        <label>Yes</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="anotherCheese" value="no" />
        <label>No</label>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>`);
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form class="steps-row-first">
    <fieldset class="radio-wrapper">
      <fieldset class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" class="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="yes" />
        <label>Yes</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="anotherCheese" value="no" />
        <label>No</label>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    /* Make sure that all of the <script> tags are right before the closing </body> tag */
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't start with a `'` you started with a `‘` in jquery fixed code

```
$('.anotherCheese').on("click", function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'yes')
    {
      $(".steps-row-first").append('<div class="radio-wrapper"> 
<div class="radio-group"> <input type="radio" 
class="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="yes"/> 
<label>Yes</label> </div><div class="radio-group"> <input 
type="radio" name="anotherCheese" value="no"/> 
<label>No</label> </div></div>');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, even still it does not work.

Comment: what is the error or what happens